# Haskell - Applying a foldl function to a list of lists

Tags: haskell

I have a function fromDigits which takes a list of int and gives it as the combination of all elements of that list.

For example, fromDigits takes [1,2,3,4,5,6] and gives 123456.

I want to be able to apply this fromDigits function to all lists within a list.

For example i want [ [1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6] ] to give [12, 34, 56].

I have been trying to accomplish this for hours and am getting nowhere. Am i going about this the complete wrong way?

The fromDigits function is as follows:

```
fromDigits = foldl addDigit 0
   where addDigit num d = 10*num + d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map fromDigits` gives you a function that does just that:

```
> map fromDigits [ [1,2] , [3,4] , [5,6] ]
[12, 34, 56]
```

`map`, like `foldl`, is one of the most basic higher-order functions. It creates a new list from the given list, by applying the given function to each element in turn.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think i was overthinking the whole process.